# Dockerfile and Docker Compose for NestJS app with PSQL DB where env vars are expected at runtime

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, nestjs

I'm Dockerizing a simple Node/JS (NestJS -- but I don't think that matters for this question) web service and have some questions. This service talks to a Postgres DB. I would like to write a `Dockerfile` that can be used to build an image of the service (let's call it `my-service`) and then write a `docker-compose.yml` that defines a service for the Postgres DB as well as a service for `my-service` that uses it. That way I can build images of `my-service` but also have a Docker Compose config for running the service and its DB at the same time together. I *think* that's the way to do this (keep me honest though!). **Kubernetes is not an option for me, just FYI.**

The web service has a top-level directory structure like so:

```
my-service/
    .env
    package.json
    package-lock.json
    src/
    <lots of other stuff>
```

Its critical to note that in its present, non-containerized form, you have to set several environment variables ahead of time, including the Postgres DB connection info (host, port, database name, username, password, etc.). The application code fetches the values of these env vars at runtime and uses them to connect to Postgres.

So, I need a way to write a `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` such that:

- if I'm just running a container of the `my-service` image by itself, and want to tell it to connect to any arbitrary Postgres DB, I can pass those env vars in as (ideally) runtime arguments on the Docker CLI command (however remember the app expects them to be set as env vars); and
- if I'm spinning up the `my-service` and its Postgres together via the Docker Compose file, I need to also specify those as runtime args in the Docker Compose CLI, then Docker Compose needs to pass them on to the container's run arguments, and then the container needs to set them as env vars for web service to use

Again, I *think* this is the correct way to go, but keep me honest!

So my best attempt -- a total WIP so far -- looks like this:

#### `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:18

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

# creates "dist" to run out of
RUN npm run build

# ideally the env vars are already set at this point via
## docker CLI arguments, so nothing to pass in here (???)
CMD [ "node", "dist/main.js" ]
```

#### `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:14.3
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${psql.password}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${psql.user}
      POSTGRES_DB: my-service-db
      PG_DATA: /var/lib/postgresql2/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql2/data
  my-service:
    container_name: my-service
    image: ???  anyway to say "build whats in the repo?"
    environment:
      ??? do I need to set anything here so it gets passed to the my-service
          container as env vars?
volumes:
  pgdata:
```

Can anyone help nudge me over the finish line here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> ??? do I need to set anything here so it gets passed to the my-service
> container as env vars?

Yes, you should pass the variables there. This is a principle of [12 factor design](https://12factor.net/config)

> need to also specify those as runtime args in the Docker Compose CLI, then Docker Compose needs to pass them on to the container's run arguments

If you don't put them directly in the YAML, will this option work for you?

```
docker-compose --env-file app.env up
```

Ideally, you also put

```
depends_on:
  postgres
```

So that when you start your service, the database will also start up.

If you want to connect to a different database instance, then you can either create a separate compose file without that database, or use a different set of variables (written out, or using `env_file`, as mentioned)

Or you can use NPM `dotenv` or `config` packages and set different `.env` files for different database environments, based on other variables, such as `NODE_ENV`, at runtime.

> ???  anyway to say "build whats in the repo?"

Use `build` instead of `image` directive.

> Kubernetes is not an option for me, just FYI

You *could* use Minikube instead of Compose... Doesn't really matter, but `kompose` exists to convert a Docker Compose into k8s resources.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer @OneCricketeer (+1) -- for the bounty would you be willing to show the exact Dockerfile/docker-compose.yml (based on my originals above) as well as the exact command-line invocations for building the `my-service` image and then running Docker Compose to spin a container of it (and its PSQL DB) up? Preferably passing in `POSTGRES_PASSWORD=12345` and `POSTGRES_USER=someguy` as the values? That would tie everything together for me. Thanks again!

Comment: Your existing Dockerfile seems fine. The DockerHub page for Postgres shows what you need for authentication. You would need to copy the same values into your service `environment` section. Or you can [use a `.env` file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file). Seems like you just want to know how to use Compose [`build`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/build/#build-definition) option. The only "command" you need is `docker-compose up --build`

Comment: There are also example repos using NodeJS (Express) and a database (MongoDB) [in awesome-compose repo](https://github.com/docker/awesome-compose/tree/master/react-express-mongodb/backend)

Comment: Please note the difference between the [`docker-compose --env-file`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose/#options) cli flag and the [`env_file`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#env_file) property in the compose file. Although they look very similar they do widely different things! See the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/).

Answer (score 1):

Your **`Dockerfile`** is correct. You can specify the environment variables while doing `docker run` like this:

```
docker run --name my-service -it <image> -e PG_USER='user' -e PG_PASSWORD='pass'
  -e PG_HOST='dbhost' -e PG_DATABASE='dbname' --expose <port>
```

Or you can specify the environment variables with the help of `.env` file. Let's call it `app.env`. Its content would be:

```
PG_USER=user
PG_PASSWORD=pass
PG_DATABASE=dbname
PG_HOST=dbhost
OTHER_ENV_VAR1=someval
OTHER_ENV_VAR2=anotherval
```

Now instead of specifying multiple `-e` options to `docker run` command, you can simply tell the name of the file from where the environment variables need to be picked up.

```
docker run --name my-service -it <image> --env-file app.env --expose <port>
```

In order to run postgres and your service with a single docker compose command, a few modifications need to be done in your **`docker-compose.yml`**. Let's first see the full `YAML`.

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:14.3
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: $PG_PASSWORD
      POSTGRES_USER: $PG_USER
      POSTGRES_DB: my-service-db
      PG_DATA: /var/lib/postgresql2/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql2/data
  my-service:
    container_name: my-service
    build: .   #instead of image directive, use build to tell docker what folder to build
    environment:
      PG_USER: $PG_USER
      PG_PASSWORD: $PG_PASSWORD
      PG_HOST: postgres   #note the name of the postgres service in compose yaml
      PG_DATABASE: my-service-db
      OTHER_ENV_VAR1: $OTHER_ENV_VAR1
      OTHER_ENV_VAR2: $OTHER_ENV_VAR2
    depends_on:
      postgres
volumes:
  pgdata:
```

Now you can use `docker compose up` command to run the services. If you wish to build the `my-service` container each time you can pass an optional argument `--build` like this: `docker compose up --build`.

In order to pass the environment variables from the CLI, there's only one way which is by the use of `.env` file. In your case of `docker-compose.yml` the `app.env` would look like:

```
PG_USER=user
PG_PASSWORD=pass
#PG_DATABASE=dbname   #not required as you're using 'my-service-db' as db name in compose file
#PG_HOST=dbhost       #not required as service name of postgres in compose file is being used as db host
OTHER_ENV_VAR1=someval
OTHER_ENV_VAR2=anotherval
```

Passing this `app.env` file using docker compose CLI command would look like this:

```
docker compose --env-file app.env up --build
```

PS: If you're building your `my-service` each time just for the code changes to reflect in the docker container, you could make use of bind mount instead. The updated `docker-compose.yml` in that case would look like this:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:14.3
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: $PG_PASSWORD
      POSTGRES_USER: $PG_USER
      POSTGRES_DB: my-service-db
      PG_DATA: /var/lib/postgresql2/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql2/data
  my-service:
    container_name: my-service
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app    #note the use of volumes here
    environment:
      PG_USER: $PG_USER
      PG_PASSWORD: $PG_PASSWORD
      PG_HOST: postgres
      PG_DATABASE: my-service-db
      OTHER_ENV_VAR1: $OTHER_ENV_VAR1
      OTHER_ENV_VAR2: $OTHER_ENV_VAR2
    depends_on:
      postgres
volumes:
  pgdata:
```

This way, you don't need to run docker compose build each time, making a code change in the source folder would get reflected in the docker container.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add path of your docker file in to build parameter in docker-compose.yaml file and all the environment variables in environment

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:14.3
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${psql.password}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${psql.user}
      POSTGRES_DB: my-service-db
      PG_DATA: /var/lib/postgresql2/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql2/data
  my-service:
    container_name: my-service
    image: path_to_your_dockerfile
    environment:
      your_environment_variables_here
          container as env vars?
volumes:
  pgdata
```

I am guessing that you have folder structure like this

```
project_folder/
               docker-compose.yaml
               my-service/
                           Dockerfile
                          .env
                           package.json
                           package-lock.json
                           src/
                           <lots of other stuff>
```

and your .env contains following

```
API_PORT=8082
Environment_var1=Environment_var1_value
Environment_var2=Environment_var2_value
```

So in your case your docker-compose file should look like this

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:14.3
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${psql.password}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${psql.user}
      POSTGRES_DB: my-service-db
      PG_DATA: /var/lib/postgresql2/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql2/data
  my-service:
    container_name: my-service
    image: ./my-service/
    environment:
      - API_PORT=8082
      - Environment_var1=Environment_var1_value
      - Environment_var2=Environment_var2_value 
volumes:
  pgdata
```

**FYI:** for this docker configuration your database connection host should be **postgres** (as per service name) not **localhost** and your